# Postgres SQL (Amazon Redshift) Run Commands on Startup

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a set of commands that I run every time I login into psql.  How can I run these commands automatically on psql startup?

The commands include:

```
\timing
set search_path=public,latitude;
```

Redshift uses psql (8.4.18, server 8.0.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql` has a `.psqlrc` file for just this purpose.

See [the relevant PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html), which discusses the `.psqlrc`. It's unlikely that Amazon has changed this.

Comment: This worked, thanks!  By the way, that link didn't work.  [This one](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/app-psql.html) does.

Comment: @dima Thanks. Link fixed. Typo.